# Pass data to array in rails

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails

I have below drop down.

```
<select class="form-control input-lg dm-recipients" id="recipients" name="recipients[]" multiple="multiple">
 <% if @di.size >= 1 and !@di.include?("data") %>
  <% @di.each do |d| %>
     <% @members.each do |user| %>    
         <% name = user['first'] + " " + user['last'] %>   
        <option value="<%= user["id"] %>"><%= name&.try(:strip) %></option> 
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
</select>
```

In @di object I have field call recipients and it saves array of recipient ID.  i want to pre-select options which have these recipients IDs.**(d['recipients'])**
To do that I have to use javascript below code will do what I want.

```
var element = document.getElementById('recipients');

// Set Values
 var values = ["d729c11b-e5fa-4787-bc89-4fad7c247e35"];
  for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
   element.options[i].selected = values.indexOf(element.options[i].value) >= 0;
 }
```

Here I passed recipient ID for my testing purpose. But I want to pass array of recipients to **var values**

I am very new for rails and try to pass array. But no luck. can Some one help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, I don't think you have the right approach by wanting to do this in JS.

For example you could set a variable that has all the values that you want in a array, and you could then `collection_select` that array?

Or maybe you could use a `hidden_field` for which you require the params in your controller?